# HTML list information into popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'd like to first off say sorry for my bad wording.

I have this code:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong><?php echo $row['id']; ?></strong></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['amountOwed']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['hoursComplete']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['hoursAuthorized']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nextPayment']; ?></td>
<?php if($session->isAdmin()){ ?>
<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm not to sure how to do the next part. I'm trying to make it so when I click the button it will open a pop up window using the code below and display the data.

Once again I am attempting to get the data from the above selected and echoing it into the input fields in this code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Editing</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<form action="report.php" method="POST" id="reppur" name="reppur1">


<input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="status" type="text" id="status" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="amountOwed" type="text" id="amountOwed" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="hoursComplete" type="text" id="hoursComplete" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="hoursAuthorized" type="text" id="hoursAuthorized" class="form-control" required><br>
<input name="nextPayment" type="text" id="nextPayment" class="form-control" required><br>



</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it means that when you click on the `<a>` tag then a modal is open and it show the information which you set in the table ?

Comment: Echo directly in input fields

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that I can think of that you can do to achieve what you want. One of them is going to require some ajax.

1. If that is the only table row on the page, you can assign each TD an ID and use Javascript to populate the fields. So for example if your first TD is the name, you would do `<td id='name'>` and populate the corresponding element using `$('#name').text()`.

Or...

2. If you have multiple rows, store the ID of the table row in the row itself. You can just implement an edit button that calls a function to populate your input fields with the row ID as the parameter. Then, when you want to go and edit a specific row, you pass the ID of the row to your Javascript code, execute an AJAX call to fetch the row with that specific ID, and use the results to populate the values of your modal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that, one possible way would be:

Define which input will receive the column data, for this, you can add a data property on your td, and add a css class. e.g:

```
<tr class='row'>
     <td data-field='name' class='input-column'><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
     <td data-field='username' class='input-column'><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Then, you can you can use this script to set the values:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-info').click(function(){

        // Get columns by class
        $columns = $(this).closest('.row').find('.input-column');

        $.each($columns, function(k, v){
             // Setting value of elements
             $('#' + $(v).data('field')).val($(v).text());
        });

        // Here you show your modal.

    });

});
```

On `data-field` you have to use the field ID, otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: I am completely lost. Please explain. I am 100% new to this.

Answer (score 0):

To add each piece of information into a corresponding input field you can use jQuery. I guess I would do something like this: I would add a class "editable" to all table cells that can be edited. I would also add a data-field (just an example) attribute, which will hold the id of corresponding input field. So, something like this:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong><?php echo $row['id']; ?></strong></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="name"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="username"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="status"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="amountOwed"><?php echo $row['amountOwed']; ?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="hoursComplete"><?php echo $row['hoursComplete']; ?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="hoursAuthorized"><?php echo $row['hoursAuthorized']; ?></td>
<td class="editable" data-field="nextPayment"><?php echo $row['nextPayment']; ?></td>
<?php if($session->isAdmin()){ ?>
<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></td>
<?php } ?>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, the jQuery. You add a click listener for the modal trigger. In that listener, you target all the cells from that row that have class editable, loop through them, and populate the input field with corresponding ID with the cell text:

```
$('a[data-togle="modal"]').click(function(){
    //loop through all cells that can be edited
    $(this).parent('td').siblings('.editable').each(function(){
        //and create input selector from the data-form attribute
        $('input#' + $(this).data('field')).attr('value', $(this).text());
    });
});
```

That should do it, but all based on assumption your cells will contain only the text from the database, and that you will wire up data-field and input IDs correctly, etc...

Comment: I don't understand, where do I put the jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had some basic knowledge. Then your problem really isn't how you are going to solve this, but you need to cover some ground to get to this. If you are not familiar with javascript at all, then don't bother with jQuery. Go through some JS courses, tutorials, and when you feel confident enough, try jQuery, and then some real development.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just echo the variable in input value for example:

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $row['username'] ; ?>" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: This only works when there is only one line in the DB.

Comment: @user3724476 one line means? It just an example for one field